# How to make string bold in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to make a string bolder in code behind using C# .NET?

I tried:

```
string TypeofDay = "<span style='font-weight: bold'>Type Of Day</span> ";
txtbox.Text = TypeofDay + ": " + "Delivery Day"
```

I am concatenating TypeofDay(**bold**) and "Delivery Day" to display in a textbox.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear.  Can you give more details?

Comment: where are you outputting this string? RichTextBox? WebBrowserForm?

Comment: @DannyG You can look at the edited code. Let me know if i am still not clear. Thank you!

Comment: @axon I am displaying it in a textbox on a webpage.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PS. I am concatenating few bold strings and some other strings to display in a textbox.

A HTML text box does not support this. ASP.NET (usually) generates HTML; if HTML does not support this, you cannot solve it from the server side.

Comment: So its not possible :-( Now, i understand why i cant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't make some bits bold and some bits not bold, in an `<asp:TextBox>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make text bolder by enclosing text value in tags. You must change attribute of a control that displays that text for example by setting its CSS class or changing code-behind property:

```
txbSendMessageBody.Font.Bold = true;
```

Comment: i did not want the whole text to use bold. Just a part of it. Gurus have just made me understand why it cant be done!

Answer (score 1):

TextBox, no, however you could use a label.

```
myLabel.text = "<b>bold text</b> normal text <u>underlined text</u> <span style='font-size:Large; color:Red'>Big red text</span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky alternative can be to use Unicode bold characters
http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Type+Of+Day

```
txtbox.Text = "  :  "
```

Answer (score 0):

You could layer a div on top of the textbox.  Since the text formatting would change anyway once the user started typing, you can just hide the div once focus is given to the div, thus showing the text box.  If nothing is entered and focus is lost, show the div again.